# A question related to slowly oscillating functions from De-Koninck&Luca-Analytic NT

Tags: analytic-number-theory, summation-by-parts, slowly-varying-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a function for which there exists a constant $0<A\in\mathbb{R}$ such that: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\le x}f(n)=A.$

Show that:
$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n\le x}f(n)\log(n)=Ax\log(x)(1+o(1)).$

I've been able to deduce the following:

1)For $0<M\in\mathbb{R}$, a function $g:[M,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous on $[M,\infty)$ is said to be slowly oscillating if $\forall\epsilon>0\quad\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x\epsilon)}{f(x)}=1.$

Now, proposition 1.9 in De-Koninck&Luca states that a function $f$ that is once-continuously differentiable on $[M,\infty)$ is slowly oscillating iff $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_M^x\frac{dt}{f(t)}=\frac{x}{f(x)}(1+o(1))$.

It's easy enough to verify from the definition that the function: $\frac{1}{A\log(x)}$ is slowly oscillating, and hence by proposition (1.9) $\quad\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_1^xA\log(t)dt=Ax\log(x)(1+o(1)).$ This can obviously be seen by a direct calculation but I wish to emphasize the apparent necessity of proposition (1.9) in the solution to my question.

2)$\frac{f(n)}{n}\to 0$. Maybe useful but I can't see how.

I'm unable to use the first statement of the question in order to deduce any conditions on $f(n)$ which might allow us to approximate it using an integral, or maybe translate between the appearances of $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\log(n)$, although these expressions always hang out together so it seems like a natural idea.

Working back from my first deduction has not led me too far either. A full solution, or a sequence of (not too vague please) hints will both be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try with Abel's summation formula

Comment: It seems you are overcomplicating things. One doesn't need anything about slowly varying functions, just summation by parts. The most convenient form of summation by parts here is [Abel's summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) (ahistorically, integration by parts of a Stieltjes integral), but other forms aren't hard either. The premise can be written as $$F(x) := \sum_{n \leqslant x} f(n) = Ax + o(x)\,.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, I wasn't been able to see your statement for $\sum_{n\le x}f(n)$ on my own for some reason. I've made progress on the problem, and all that remains(I think) is a formal justification of interchanging the limit and integral that appear when one applies Abel's formula. When I have a formal answer, I willl write it here.

Comment: I overlooked it before: The limit in the "Show that" line makes no sense. On the right hand an $x$ appears, on the left it would drop out by taking the limit (which under the given assumptions could be interpreted as $+\infty$). What makes sense and is correct is that $$\sum_{n \leqslant x} f(n)\log n = Ax\log (x) + o(x\log x) = Ax\log(x)\cdot \bigl(1 + o(1)\bigr)\,.$$ Or, which is a different way to express the same, $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x\log x} \sum_{n \leqslant x} f(n)\log n = A\,.$$